# Function that creates an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create a function that takes input from user and returns an array with all the numbers from 1 to the passed number as an argument. Example: createArray(10) should return [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]. I came up with this solution:

```
function createArray(input) {
  var value = 0;
  var array = [];
 for (i=0;i<input;i++) {
  value++;
 array.push(value)
 console.log(array)
 }
}

createArray(12);
```

What is the correct and better way of doing it?

Answer (score 5):

I would prefer to use `Array.from`:

```js
const createArray = length => Array.from(
  { length },
  // Mapper function: i is the current index in the length being iterated over:
  (_, i) => i + 1
)
console.log(JSON.stringify(createArray(10)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(createArray(5)));
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for the extra variable just do this:

```
function createArray(input) {
  var array = [];

  for (i = 0; i <= input; i++) {
    array.push(i);
  }
  return array;
}
```